# Error while installing native-base in react-native project

Tags: npm

I am doing a project on react-native in that when I used to install native base package it is showing the error.I had tried npm install native-base command , npm install --legacy--peer-deps command eventhough it had not fixed.

**My package.json code:**

{

"name": "animal-feedmart",

"version": "1.0.0",

"main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",

"scripts": {

```
"start": "expo start",

"android": "expo start --android",

"ios": "expo start --ios",

"web": "expo start --web",

"eject": "expo eject"
```

},

"dependencies": {

```
"expo": "~44.0.0",

"expo-status-bar": "~1.2.0",

"native-base": "^2.15.2",

"react": "17.0.1",

"react-dom": "17.0.1",

"react-native": "0.64.3",

"react-native-base": "^1.1.0",

"react-native-web": "0.17.1"
```

},

"devDependencies": {

```
"@babel/core": "^7.12.9"
```

},

"private": true

}

**My Error:**

added 39 packages, removed 75 packages, changed 6 packages, and audited 999

packages in 13s

28 packages are looking for funding

run `npm fund` for details

26 vulnerabilities (18 moderate, 7 high, 1 critical)

To address issues that do not require attention, run:

npm audit fix

To address all issues possible (including breaking changes), run:

npm audit fix --force

Some issues need review, and may require choosing

a different dependency.

Run `npm audit` for details.

If required I can share other details of my project. Please help me to solve this error

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

this problem has arisen in the react new version.

when you wanna install native-base package, you shoud use --force flag.

```
npm install native-base <other_pkg> --force
```

Answer (score 0):

`npm audit` automatically runs when you install a package with `npm install`.

That's why I believe your question might have already been answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74578722/14056591